# "share it" social media buttons on youtube video on my website

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube

I am building a website with youtube videos listed and my spec for the site is to have share it buttons below that would allow you to share it on social media platforms. Is there a way to allow this to happen I can't seem to figure it out. My spec looks like:[image]

I see there is a link share option built in at the top of the video:

[image]

but is there a way to always have the share options showing and a way to customize the options as far as social media choices and icons that are used?

Comment: The embed is not that configurable. You'd have to build something custom.

Comment: any suggestions on how would i go about doing that

Comment: what exactly are you sharing?  the video (url to youtube.com)?  or the page that you are displaying the video on (your url)?

Comment: the video (url to youtube.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Social platforms vary in how you can do this, but most have Javascript SDKs  or simple embeds available to create sharing buttons. It typically involves pasting some javascript code on the page, and/or generating a button embed on their developer site, and pasting the button on your page (typically an iframe, or a div).

For instance Facebook has a Javascript SDK, as well as a simple embed for share buttons. The simple embed code looks something like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DXXXXXXX&layout=button&size=small&mobile_iframe=true&appId=XXXXXXXXX&width=59&height=20" width="59" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Whereas the Javascript SDK embed looks something like this:

```
//include the SDK:
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11&appId=XXXXXXXXXX';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

// include the button
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXX" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DXXXXXXXX&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
```

> In your case you have a specification for a *custom button*, so you'd have to hack up the generated button somewhat and apply the linking mechanism to your own button.

**However, I don't advise this for a couple reasons:**

1. **Legality:** You may be breaking the terms of use for the social network's
   sharing button by doing this, however I can't say this for certain, you'd have to read all that.
2. **Usability:** The designers and UI/UX experts at these networks have put a lot of time, research and money into designing these elements.  These buttons are immediately recognized by your users, and are branded in a way to promote the recongition of that particular social network.  What you're proposing is changing that.  Your designer may think, "*well my buttons I designed match our site better*".  Well maybe, but orange buttons aren't what your audience is used to using, and I guarantee the social network's own buttons will perform better.  At the very least if they insist on using these, you should A/B test them against the standard buttons, so you can have direct evidence of what performs best. The icons your designer are suggesting using are typically the type you would see when a site is referring you to their own social network, not to invoke an action like sharing or liking.
3. **Configurability**: When you use your own buttons you lose the ability to utilize additional tools the network's buttons provide such as share counters.
4. **Longevity**: By hacking up these buttons it's going to make future changes difficult when the network updates code for their SDK or the code for the embed methods.

I'm not sure what road you'll take, but following are links to the Developer pages where you can generate buttons, to get you started:

**Facebook**:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/#

**Twitter**:

https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button

**Instagram**:

Not gonna happen. Instagram is a photo sharing network built for mobile users.  There's no direct way to share someone's Youtube video to your Instagram feed (at least none that I'm aware of).

**Youtube**:

Youtube does not offer a share button.  Again, what would you be sharing?  How do you post someone's Youtube video to your Youtube account?

**As an alternative:**

There are other services that provide sharing widgets which encompass a bunch of different social sites and sharing tools ("AddThis", "ShareThis" Google them). Personally I don't like using them, because they create a lot of overhead and my experience with them is that they are quite slow.

**If it were me:**

I would simply enable the sharing tools in each Youtube embed.  It's a recognizable icon that any user used to sharing anything will recognize.  It also gives you many more options.  This goes back to usability/familiarity. If any of your users has shared YouTube videos, and they wish to share yours, they're going to be looking for whats familiar - that icon - not the orange buttons.  And if you get talked into doing something you disagree with by a designer, you can always A/B test.  Numbers don't lie.